# Cut the string in c#

Tags: c#, split

How to split this string at every `\n` character AND replace with `;` character and finally put them in an array.

After that, if the line in the array is longer than 60 characters, split again, just on the last space before char 60. Then repeat when the second part is still over 60 long?

My code is:

```
var testString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy \n text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, \nwhen an unknown printer took a galley of \n type and scrambled \n it to make a type specimen";

const int maxLength = 60;
string[] lines = testString.Replace("\n", ";").Split(';');
foreach (string line in lines)
{
 if (line.Length > maxLength)
 {
   string[] tooLongLine = line.Split(' ');
 }
}
```

result:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy;
>
> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
>   the
>
> industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,;
>
> when an unknown printer took a galley of;
>
> type and scrambled;
>
> it to make a type specimen;

Comment: You know you can just split on `\n` instead of doing a replace first.

Comment: yes, but i need to replace the \n character with ;

Comment: I'm confused.. Is the output not what you were expecting?

Comment: i dont know how to "put together" the final array

Comment: Split on \n like @juharr said and then append a semicolon to the end of each line

Comment: @EastonBornemeier But `string.Split` will get rid of the delimiter, so you just need to add the semi-colon after the split.

Comment: So what you're asking is how to print the sentences at the end?

Comment: how to put the whole text in one array

Comment: Can you give us the **expected result**, instead of giving us the result of something that you do not want.

Comment: I don't think you want to split a long line on *every* space, just on the last space before char 60. And repeat when the second part is still over 60 long.

Comment: What if you have a line that's longer than 60 and doesn't have any spaces?

Comment: So you want to wrap the text based on 60 characters?

Comment: @HansKesting yes you are right. if the line doesnt't have any spaces than cut at 59 char.

Comment: the result is at the bottom of my question.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to first split on newlines (adding a `;`) and then for longer lines replace the single array item with two or more. The end result is a single array of short lines.

Comment: Question: You split on `'\n'` but if there is an `';'` in the string before the remplace is it a split point to?

Comment: If your max length is 60 then the your second line is wrong as it has 71 total characters.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It seems like the OP wants to type set lines to a certain length, but how they came up witht the split for the second line based on a max length of 60 means they either don't count spaces toward the total length (which would be odd) or they want a length of 71 or more.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd keep track of the desired strings in a list.  Then split on the `\n` and for each resulting string append the semicolon, then check if it's too long.  Then the trick is to continue to shorten the string by finding the last space before the max length.  If there isn't a space then just truncate to the max length.

```
string input = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy \n text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, \nwhen an unknown printer took a galley of \n type and scrambled \n it to make a type specimen";
int maxLength = 60;

List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach(string line in input.Split('\n'))
{
    string current = line.Trim() + ";";
    int start = 0;
    while(current.Length - start > maxLength)
    {
        int depth = Math.Min(start + maxLength, current.Length);
        int splitAt = current.LastIndexOf(" ",  depth, depth - start);
        if(splitAt == -1)
            splitAt = start + maxLength;

        results.Add(current.Substring(start, splitAt - start));
        while(splitAt < current.Length && current[splitAt] == ' ')
            splitAt++;
        start = splitAt;            
    }

    if(start < current.Length)
        results.Add(current.Substring(start));
}

foreach(var line in results)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

That code gives the following results

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy;
>
> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
>
> has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
>
> 1500s,;
>
> when an unknown printer took a galley of;
>
> type and scrambled;
>
> it to make a type specimen;

This differs from your results because you seem to allow more than 60 characters, or maybe you only count non spaces.  I'll leave it up to you to make changes if that's what you actually want.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Count must be positive and count must refer to a location within the string/array/collection.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yeah, I had `LastIndexOf` setup wrong.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: and it needs to be an array

Comment: Then just do `string[] myArray = results.ToArray();` at the end.

Comment: FYI I also need to fix it to truncate the spaces it breaks on.  I'll update in a minute

Comment: Updated to trim spaces.